# What will happen if add UIView as a subview to itself

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

What are all bad things doing it?
What will happen if changing properties on it?
Will it go in some kind of recursion?

Comment: Will crash whey you will try to show .

Comment: Can you make yourself as your father??

Comment: More "Can you make yourself your own son"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the app would go into an endless recursion and crash eventually, as soon as you try and show it.

More on that, at this fine article by Mike Ash - https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-01-10-lets-break-cocoa.html

Answer (score 0):

Will crash: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'"